# Cual seria la expresión regular para que no muestre los archivos ocultos por el sistema PHP

Tags: php, regex

Al recorrer los directorios y mostrar todos los archivos .XML, tambien me muestra en salida los archivos ocultos por el sistema, que son la copia de los archivos XML, me gustaría opiniones de como evitar los archivos ocultos.

```
 $regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, **'/^.+\.xml$/i'**, 
 RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Me parece que faltan detalles en tu pregunta. ¿Estás usando algún framework? Esto no me parece puro PHP...

Comment: estoy utilizando symfony, si es PHP puro solo que utiliza la clase RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

Comment: ¿Y revisaste si esa clase tiene algún método o parámetro para no mostrar los archivos ocultos? Eso debería constar en la pregunta. Cuando uno usa una clase debe revisar la documentación, los métodos que tiene o los parámetros que acepta.

Comment: si,  mi problema esta en que la expresión regular creo no esta indicando como no mostrarme la salida de los archivos ocultos.

Comment: Realmente nunca he usado Symfony, pero me extraña que no tenga una clase o librería que te muestre los archivos de una extensión cualquiera excluyendo los archivos ocultos. O sea, una clase con un método que reciba en parámetro la extensión y algo así como una opción en la que digas : *no me traigas los archivos ocultos*.  Me parece extraño que esto haya que hacerlo con expresiones regulares. ¿?

Comment: Es verdad que yo personalmente no utilizaría `RegexIterator` que si que es una clase de php y no de `symfony`. En este caso creo que lo más adecuado podría ser `glob()`

Comment: Existe un metodo en el componente finder de symfony que te omite los archivos ocultos, pero creo que se basa unicamente en linux y toma como ocultos los archivos con . delante. es el metodo ignoreDotFiles

Answer (score 0):

La implementación dependerá de tu hosting/máquina donde tengas el intérprete php.

En Linux/Unix cualquier fichero que empiece por punto `.` se considera un fichero oculto.

```
.hola.txt => Oculto
hola.txt  => Visible
```

Así pues, simplemente te bastaría con mirar si el primer caracter del string es un punto para saber si el fichero es oculto

`substr($mi_string, 0, 1) == '.'`

Sin embargo, en Windows se consideraría una propiedad o atributo del fichero. Deberías hacer una llamada al sistema para evaluar esta propiedad.

Aquí tienes un método que te serviría. Combina la llamada via exec y dentro lo que hay es código `.bat`

```
function is_hidden_file($fn) {

    $attr = trim(exec('FOR %A IN ("'.$fn.'") DO @ECHO %~aA'));

    if($attr[3] === 'h')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

La función está sacada de este [comentario](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php#87161) de php.net

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso, si estas utilizando symfony y utilizas el componente finder https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html, tienes el metodo:

**ignoreDotFiles**

Como ejemplo, podrias utilizar lo siguiente:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in(__DIR__)->ignoreDotFiles(true);
```

**NOTA:**

la propia documentacion indica que los archivos "hidden" son los que considera aquellos con nombre iniciado en . Esto es asi en determinados S.O., pero en windows concretamente se utilizan atributos de archivo.

Tal como te indica @julio, quizas deberias utilizar un metodo como el anterior para asegurarte de los atributos en sistemas windows.